# Telerik Radgrid Filter formatting

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, filter, telerik, radgrid

I have a radgrid with filtering enabled, I need to set the filter to have "text-transform: uppercase." How can I reference the default filter textbox in the vb code, or is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet. Let me know if any concern.

**ASPX**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .RadGrid_Default .rgFilterBox {
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1" />
            <telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="scrCode_Outlier" runat="server">
                <script type="text/javascript">

                </script>
            </telerik:RadScriptBlock>
            <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" AllowFilteringByColumn="true">
                <GroupingSettings CaseSensitive="false" />
                <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                    <Columns>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" UniqueName="Name" HeaderText="Name"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    </Columns>
                </MasterTableView>
            </telerik:RadGrid>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**ASPX.VB**

```
Protected Sub RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(sender As Object, e As GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs)
        Dim data As dynamic = New () {New With { _
            Key .ID = 1, _
            Key .Name = "Name1" _
        }, New With { _
            Key .ID = 2, _
            Key .Name = "Name2" _
        }}
        RadGrid1.DataSource = data
End Sub
```

Based on your skin please replace your skin name with default  "RadGrid_Default".